# Yes/No Button Toggle Design

Tags: usability, accessibility, radio-buttons, toggle

So, 2 design options for how to style the toggle button for Y/N answers.  There could be anywhere from 4-12 questions on a single page.  Which one is better and why?

(I have a few thoughts on this already but want to see what others have to say as well)

Option #1

[image: Option #1]

Option #2

[image: Option #2]

Comment: I don't particularly like either. For the example question, I'd just make a check box with the 'question'  as a statement next to it `[ ] Location is the same as Mailing Location` for no, `[@] Location is the same as Mailing Location` for yes

Comment: why not use a regular toggle instead of buttons? they look quite confusing to me. This being said, if you have 4 to 12 questions, then I'd use just inline `radio inputs`

Comment: Use separate buttons to avoid the confusion of a toggle. But your use of the toggle should be clear enough, especially with the check-mark and the plain text identification for each option spelled out.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a toggle button.  The second seems more obvious as to which is selected.  In fact, the first one, I can't tell which one is selected.

Comment: In option 2, what is the icon used if No is selected? Is it a tick or a cross?

Comment: Is there a particular advantage over radio buttons that you are pursuing?

Comment: Thanks for the input and questions!  The goal of using these (based on Bootstrap btn-group) is to provide better scanning when there are several on the page.  Regular radio buttons can be harder to read/visually differentiate in this case because of the very short labels (Yes or No).  The button groups also naturally increase the target size for selection.

The checkmark in option 2 would be used to show the selected state so it would show with either the Yes or the No along with the light background color change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options still have many open questions on accessibility, but I would go with option #2.

Because your question seems to focus only on the visual aspects of the UI, I’m not going into details about exposed roles and states.

### Behaviour

Accessibility role and visual presentation are an affordance, they communicate expected behaviour: These buttons do not take any actions, they set a state, an answer. This is the behaviour of *radio buttons*.

Buttons glued to each other (and not in a toolbar) communicate that behaviour better than buttons apart. That behaviour is

- The button state is changed by means of arrow keys
- Only one of the buttons can be pressed/checked at a time and keeps that state

See [Bootstrap’s Radio Button Group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/button-group/#btnradio3)

### Use of colour

Another aspect is that you use only colour to distinguish the button’s state in option #1, which fails accessibility criteria. The icon in #2 solves that issue, if it is shown only for the pressed or checked state.

From the [WCAG, Use of Color](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/#use-of-color)

> Color is not used as the only visual means of conveying information, indicating an action, prompting a response, or distinguishing a visual element.

Also, contrast of the leading question is way better in option #2.

Comment: Thanks Andy!  Yeah, option 2 is based on BS Button Group and updated styling to match company design standards with the addition of the checkmark to help visually show the selected state.  Option 1 is what is currently in the application that was done before I started and I don't care for it because of accessibility and they just feel/look like traditional buttons, not form selections.